# System notification window stuck causes the program to get stuck[Cocoa][Mac OSX]?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to show a notification window in a Mac application.Something that would come up in the trial version of the application.The window would be unmovable for 30 seconds(and it would have a counter counting down to 0).After 30 seconds it would continue execution.

Here is the code.

```
   _systemNotificationWindow = [[SystemNotificationWindow alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"SystemNotificationWindow"];
        NSLog(@"1111");
        [self.systemNotificationWindow setActionDelegate:self];


         [self.systemNotificationWindow startTimer:30];
        NSLog(@"2222");
        [self.systemNotificationWindow showWindow:self];


        NSLog(@"3333");

        NSLog(@"4444");
```

The code is stuck at this line

> [self.systemNotificationWindow showWindow:self];

It shows the window but neither the timer is working nor the window is going away after 30 seconds.Alsoo 3333 and 4444 are not being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing an event loop to control the timer, so I'm guessing that you're displaying the window before an event loop has been created.

You can read more about events [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) and run loops [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: +1 .Can you edit my code to include the event loop?I am new to cocoa and it would take me a lot of time to understand these topics.It would be helpful if you could just tell me the line to add.

Comment: Sorry, if I knew exactly what methods you needed, I would have answered the question that way. I've not had to create event loops myself yet, in Objective-C. If no-one else can provide it, you can either read the docs and work out what you need, or delay the display of that window in your application, so that the main event loop has been created before you start the timer.